# demonstrate that function is increasing in intervals that are multiples of pi?

Tags: derivatives

I have the derivative:

$$- \frac1{x^2} +   1   + \frac{\cos^2(x)}{\sin^2(x)}$$

and am supposed to show that this is positive for all $x \in (n\pi, (n+1)\pi)$.

How exactly am I supposed to do that? I'm thinking there's a trick I'm supposed to use, but can't figure it out.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Have a look at [this help page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to see how to use MathJax for mathematical expressions. Note that the trigonometric part of your expression is $\cot^2(x)$ so you need to show that
$$\cot^2(x) > \frac1{x^2} - 1$$ or that $$\frac1{\sin^2(x)} > \frac1{x^2} \Leftrightarrow \sin^2 x < x^2$$ in the given intervals.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $1 + \frac{\cos^2 x}{\sin^2 x} = \frac{1}{\sin^2 x}$, so all you need to do is compare $x^2$ with $\sin^2 x$.